# How to set up IBLOCK route for Bitrix system with multiple sites?

Tags: php, bitrix

I need to set up a site version in second language on a C1 Bitrix system. I have chosen to use the Bitrix multi-site feature for this and set up the second language as another site. Everything fine until I get to IBlock objects. On the second site, the IBLOCK details won't work.

In default site, the address of open IBLOCK woud be like this, and it works just fine: http://artspace.ua/projects/details/153/
On the second site, address would be http://artspace.ua/en/projects/details/153/, but it does not work. What am I missing? Where should I even begin?
The system behind this is  Bitrix Site Manager 14.9.3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Site folder option to `/en/` in bitrix multi-site feature for this site.

You template url seems like `#SITE_DIR#/projects/details/#ELEMENT_ID#/`

Also you need edit urlrewrite.php and add somethink like that:

```
array(
    "CONDITION" => "#^/en/projects/#",
    "RULE" => "",
    "ID" => "",
    "PATH" => "/en/projects/index.php",
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went under System Settings -> Websites -> Websites, and there I can see a list with 2 sites, first one being the original one in Russian, with "/" configured as site folder. The second one - english version, has "/en/" for folder. I've also added the code you provided to the urlrewrite.php. So far no change. Isn't the "#^/en/projects/#" part related to the project list instead of the details view? And what do i have to do with the template url you posted (#SITE_DIR#/projects/details/#ELEMENT_ID#/) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Condition `"#^/en/projects/#"` means that all url started with /en/projects/ will processed by script in path /en/projects/index.php

Url template must be saved in iblock settings.

Comment: I gave up this approach. Nothing seemed to work. In the end I dumped the idea of second language as second site, instead I went with the second language for the same site.